# Best way to add attributes to User Model in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my User Model looks like:

```
    class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
       def self.up
         create_table :users do |t|
         t.string :name
         t.string :email

         t.timestamps
       end
    end

      def self.down
        drop_table :users
        end
      end
```

If I wanted add one more :attribute, is it best to create another migration file for adding a new column ([see another Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373202/how-does-one-add-an-attribute-to-a-model)) or can I just manually add t.string :name_of_new_attribute and then rake db:migrate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The proper way is to create a new migration.  In the main rails project folder, run

`rails generate migration AddDetailsToUser address:string age:integer` etc...

and then run `rake db:migrate`

An alternative to this is to edit the original migration file, reset/destroy the database and re-run all migrations.

Comment: So when I would like to add more attributes in the future, can I simply edit this migration file?

Comment: You'd be best to create another migration with the new attributes in it